# Turning multiple 0/1 variables into one in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe based on a questionaire. For one question (Highest Degree of education) it uses like a dozen binary Variables, one for each possible answer. How do i turn these binary variables into a new variable only containing the name of the highest degree? (the binary variables seem to be mutually exclusive, dont know how to effectively check that for close to 38k instances)

I googled for a solution but couldnt find anything that actually tried to turn these multiple binaries into one variable by naming the highest degree and not by simply adding all variables together

Comment: A solution to this would definitely be predicated on confirming whether the columns are mutually exclusive or not. You may be able to check this by using `rowSums` across the desired columns and seeing if any rows have a value of two or more. You may also want to edit your question to include reproducible sample data to get better, faster help. Good luck!

Comment: If they are mutually exclusive you could pivot the data to long format and then filter to keep just the `1`s.

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse, here are two possible solutions, depending on if the data is exclusive or not.

## If they are mutually exclusive

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

df_exclusive = data.frame("Id"=1:100) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    "HighDegree.Niv1" = sample(c(0, 1), size = 1), 
    "HighDegree.Niv2" = ifelse(!HighDegree.Niv1, sample(c(0, 1), size = 1), 0),
    "HighDegree.Niv3" = ifelse(!(HighDegree.Niv1 | HighDegree.Niv2), sample(c(0, 1), size = 1), 0),
    "HighDegree.Niv4" = ifelse(!(HighDegree.Niv1 | HighDegree.Niv2 | HighDegree.Niv3), sample(c(0, 1), size = 1), 0),
    "HighDegree.Niv5" = ifelse(!(HighDegree.Niv1 | HighDegree.Niv2 | HighDegree.Niv3 | HighDegree.Niv4), 1, 0)
  )
rowSums(df_exclusive[,-1]) # Exclusive: only 1 high degree per Id


df_exclusive %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = !Id,
               names_to = "HighDegree",
               names_prefix = "HighDegree.") %>%
  filter(value == 1)
```

This is the solution that was also proposed by @andrew-gustar.

## If they are **not** mutually exclusive

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

df_nonexclusive = matrix(
  sample(c(0, 1), size = 100 * 5, replace = T),
  ncol = 5,
  nrow = 100,
  dimnames = list(1:100, paste0("HighDegree.Niv", 1:5))
) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Id")
rowSums(df_nonexclusive[,-1]) # Not exclusive: more than 1 high degree per Id


df_nonexclusive %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = !Id,
               names_to = "HighDegree",
               names_prefix = "HighDegree.") %>% 
  mutate(HighDegreeOrdered = factor(
    ifelse(value, HighDegree, 0),
    levels = c(0, "Niv1", "Niv2", "Niv3", "Niv4", "Niv5"),
    ordered = T
  )) %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise("HigherDegree" = max(HighDegreeOrdered))
```

In that case, here are more details about the code:

I first simulate data since you did not include reproducible data sample. The first two rows of `df_nonexclusive` looks like this:

```
     Id HighDegree.Niv1 HighDegree.Niv2 HighDegree.Niv3 HighDegree.Niv4 HighDegree.Niv5
1     1               0               0               1               0               1
2     2               0               1               0               1               0
```

I use `pivot_longer` to pivot data. The dataframe now looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 500 × 3
      Id HighDegree value
   <int> <chr>      <dbl>
 1     1 Niv1           0
 2     1 Niv2           0
 3     1 Niv3           1
 4     1 Niv4           0
 5     1 Niv5           0
 6     2 Niv1           1
 7     2 Niv2           0
 8     2 Niv3           0
 9     2 Niv4           0
10     2 Niv5           0
# ℹ 490 more rows
```

I create a new column of class "ordered factor". It gives `HighDegree` if `value` is 1, 0 otherwise. It is ordered depending on the level of the degree. It looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 500 × 4
   Id    HighDegree value HighDegreeOrdered
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <ord>            
 1 1     Niv1           0 0                
 2 1     Niv2           0 0                
 3 1     Niv3           1 Niv3             
 4 1     Niv4           0 0                
 5 1     Niv5           1 Niv5             
 6 2     Niv1           0 0                
 7 2     Niv2           1 Niv2             
 8 2     Niv3           0 0                
 9 2     Niv4           1 Niv4             
10 2     Niv5           0 0                
# ℹ 490 more rows
```

Finally, I group by `Id` and summarise by keeping the maximum value in column `HighDegreeOrdered`. I end up with this result:

```
# A tibble: 100 × 2
   Id    HigherDegree
   <chr> <ord>       
 1 1     Niv5        
 2 10    Niv3        
 3 100   Niv4        
 4 11    Niv4        
 5 12    Niv3        
 6 13    Niv5        
 7 14    Niv5        
 8 15    Niv4        
 9 16    Niv4        
10 17    Niv5        
# ℹ 90 more rows
```